# How do I compare a value of a local MongoDB collection to a regular MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

What I'm trying to do is compare an answer the user selected (which is stored in a local MongoDB collection) to an answer that is in a regular, declared collection.

I've tried almost every cursor in every way, but I still can't get it to work. The current event code looks like this:

```
Template.question.events({
  "click .button": function(e){
    e.preventDefault;

    var init ="";
    Session.set("userValue", init)
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName("choices").length; i++){

      if (document.getElementsByName("choices")[i].checked){
        init = document.getElementsByName("choices")[i].value;
      }
    }

    var id = "";

    Answers.insert({answer: init}, function(error, result){
      if (error){
        console.log("error: " + error);
      } else if (result){
        id = result;
      }

    });


    if(Answers.findOne({_id: id}, {answer: 1}) === Quiz.findOne({_id: this._id},{answer:1})){
      console.log("The answers match.");
    } else{
      console.log("Something went wrong.");
    }
  }

});
```

So what's happening is that the console prints "Something went wrong," which means these two answers don't match up...when they are exactly the same. So I must be doing something wrong in the last if statement with the collection cursor method calls.

"Answers" is the local null MongoDB collection, while "Quiz" is the regular MongoDB collection. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT: I the keys were not matching in the databases. I made a stupid change in the middle of coding this so it completely went unnoticed. Thanks to everyone helping out (especially Challett).**

Comment: What is happening with your current implementation?

Comment: What's happening is that the "Something went wrong" message is printed in console instead of the "The answers match," which is the opposite of what I need to happen to continue further with the script.

Comment: You have a good old misunderstanding of callbacks. The callback to `Answers.insert` is called only after the current function has finished, which you can easily attest by writing a `console.log` in its `else` block.

Comment: Kyll, I have tried putting the if statements inside the callback to Answers.inset and it still gives the same message. I have tried literally everything. I have also tried using Sessions and still get the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is coming forth because in Mongo the _id of the object is passed along with the specified fields and the way that javascript handles object equality.  Just because two objects have the same fields and values does not mean that `object1 === object2` will return true.  Instead, you should be comparing the values of the field that you are looking at instead assuming that they are not objects.

To fix this, you should implement the following:

```
var solution = Answers.findOne({_id: id}, {answer: 1}),
    quizSubmission = Quiz.findOne({_id: this._id},{answer:1}));
if(solution.answer === quizSubmission.answer{
          console.log("The answers match.");
    } else {
          console.log("Something went wrong.");
    }
```

Instead of:

```
if(Answers.findOne({_id: id}, {answer: 1}) === Quiz.findOne({_id: this._id},{answer:1})){
      console.log("The answers match.");
    } else{
      console.log("Something went wrong.");
    }
```

To solve the issue that kyll has brought forth, you can place this code inside of the callback of the insert.  If you do this you will need to assign this._id to a variable before calling `Answers.insert()`

For example:

```
var currentId = this._id;
Answers.insert({answer: init}, function(error, result){
      if (error){
        console.log("error: " + error);
      } else if (result){
        id = result;
        var solution = Answers.findOne({_id: id}, {answer: 1}),
            quizSubmission = Quiz.findOne({_id: currentId},{answer:1}));
        if(solution.answer === quizSubmission.answer){
            console.log("The answers match.");
        } else {
            console.log("Something went wrong.");
        }
      }

    });
```

Comment: Yeah, tried this before but still gives the same message.

Comment: As kyll mentioned, you have two issues.  My latest code block should solve both of them

Comment: Still get the same result. I tried this same method yesterday as well, since the id variable is empty outside the insert callback.

Comment: Well let's find out why then.  Edit your question to include the output from `console.log(Answers.findOne({_id: id}, {answer: 1, _id: 0}))` and `console.log(Quiz.findOne({_id: currentId},{answer:1, _id: 0}))` inside of your equality if statement

Comment: Console logging it inside the if statement brings no error. It prints both the collections with their keys.

Comment: A third problem with your code is object equality in javascript.  `var cat1 = {name:'cat'}, cat2 = {name:'cat'}` `cat1 === cat2` will output false.  See my latest edit .

Comment: quizSubmission.answer is undefined inside the if statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90704/discussion-between-challett-and-mabeh-al-zuq-yadeek).